# All tags in head are moved to body when blade file is rendered with Hostinger

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade, shared-hosting

I have a standard welcome page of Laravel, that I host on Hostinger. Only the problem is that all my tags in my head are moved to the body when I host the app on Hostinger. This does not happen when I run the application locally.

Below is the blade file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.bunny.net">
        <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=figtree:400,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- Styles -->
        <style>
            /* ! tailwindcss v3.2.4 | MIT License | https://tailwindcss.com */*,::after,::before{box-sizing:border-box;border-width:0;border-style:solid;border-color:#e5e7eb}::after,::before{--tw-content:''}html{line-height:1.5;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-moz-tab-size:4;tab-size:4;font-family:Figtree, sans-serif;font-feature-settings:normal}body{margin:0;line-height:inherit}hr{height:0;color:inherit;border-top-width:1px}abbr:where([title]){-webkit-text-decoration:underline dotted;text-decoration:underline dotted}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit}a{color:inherit;text-decoration:inherit}b,strong{font-weight:bolder}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:ui-monospace, SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;font-size:1em}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sub{bottom:-.25em}sup{top:-.5em}table{text-indent:0;border-color:inherit;border-collapse:collapse}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:100%;font-weight:inherit;line-height:inherit;color:inherit;margin:0;padding:0}button,select{text-transform:none}[type=button],[type=reset],[type=submit],button{-webkit-appearance:button;background-color:transparent;background-image:none}:-moz-focusring{outline:auto}:-moz-ui-invalid{box-shadow:none}progress{vertical-align:baseline}::-webkit-inner-spin-button,::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}[type=search]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;outline-offset:-2px}::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}::-webkit-file-upload-button{-webkit-appearance:button;font:inherit}summary{display:list-item}blockquote,dd,dl,figure,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,hr,p,pre{margin:0}fieldset{margin:0;padding:0}legend{padding:0}menu,ol,ul{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0}textarea{resize:vertical}input::placeholder,textarea::placeholder{opacity:1;color:#9ca3af}[role=button],button{cursor:pointer}:disabled{cursor:default}audio,canvas,embed,iframe,img,object,svg,video{display:block;vertical-align:middle}img,video{max-width:100%;height:auto}[hidden]{display:none}*, ::before, ::after{--tw-border-spacing-x:0;--tw-border-spacing-y:0;--tw-translate-x:0;--tw-translate-y:0;--tw-rotate:0;--tw-skew-x:0;--tw-skew-y:0;--tw-scale-x:1;--tw-scale-y:1;--tw-pan-x: ;--tw-pan-y: ;--tw-pinch-zoom: ;--tw-scroll-snap-strictness:proximity;--tw-ordinal: ;--tw-slashed-zero: ;--tw-numeric-figure: ;--tw-numeric-spacing: ;--tw-numeric-fraction: ;--tw-ring-inset: ;--tw-ring-offset-width:0px;--tw-ring-offset-color:#fff;--tw-ring-color:rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);--tw-ring-offset-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-ring-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow-colored:0 0 #0000;--tw-blur: ;--tw-brightness: ;--tw-contrast: ;--tw-grayscale: ;--tw-hue-rotate: ;--tw-invert: ;--tw-saturate: ;--tw-sepia: ;--tw-drop-shadow: ;--tw-backdrop-blur: ;--tw-backdrop-brightness: ;--tw-backdrop-contrast: ;--tw-backdrop-grayscale: ;--tw-backdrop-hue-rotate: ;--tw-backdrop-invert: ;--tw-backdrop-opacity: ;--tw-backdrop-saturate: ;--tw-backdrop-sepia: }::-webkit-backdrop{--tw-border-spacing-x:0;--tw-border-spacing-y:0;--tw-translate-x:0;--tw-translate-y:0;--tw-rotate:0;--tw-skew-x:0;--tw-skew-y:0;--tw-scale-x:1;--tw-scale-y:1;--tw-pan-x: ;--tw-pan-y: ;--tw-pinch-zoom: ;--tw-scroll-snap-strictness:proximity;--tw-ordinal: ;--tw-slashed-zero: ;--tw-numeric-figure: ;--tw-numeric-spacing: ;--tw-numeric-fraction: ;--tw-ring-inset: ;--tw-ring-offset-width:0px;--tw-ring-offset-color:#fff;--tw-ring-color:rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);--tw-ring-offset-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-ring-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow-colored:0 0 #0000;--tw-blur: ;--tw-brightness: ;--tw-contrast: ;--tw-grayscale: ;--tw-hue-rotate: ;--tw-invert: ;--tw-saturate: ;--tw-sepia: ;--tw-drop-shadow: ;--tw-backdrop-blur: ;--tw-backdrop-brightness: ;--tw-backdrop-contrast: ;--tw-backdrop-grayscale: ;--tw-backdrop-hue-rotate: ;--tw-backdrop-invert: ;--tw-backdrop-opacity: ;--tw-backdrop-saturate: ;--tw-backdrop-sepia: }::backdrop{--tw-border-spacing-x:0;--tw-border-spacing-y:0;--tw-translate-x:0;--tw-translate-y:0;--tw-rotate:0;--tw-skew-x:0;--tw-skew-y:0;--tw-scale-x:1;--tw-scale-y:1;--tw-pan-x: ;--tw-pan-y: ;--tw-pinch-zoom: ;--tw-scroll-snap-strictness:proximity;--tw-ordinal: ;--tw-slashed-zero: ;--tw-numeric-figure: ;--tw-numeric-spacing: ;--tw-numeric-fraction: ;--tw-ring-inset: ;--tw-ring-offset-width:0px;--tw-ring-offset-color:#fff;--tw-ring-color:rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);--tw-ring-offset-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-ring-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow-colored:0 0 #0000;--tw-blur: ;--tw-brightness: ;--tw-contrast: ;--tw-grayscale: ;--tw-hue-rotate: ;--tw-invert: ;--tw-saturate: ;--tw-sepia: ;--tw-drop-shadow: ;--tw-backdrop-blur: ;--tw-backdrop-brightness: ;--tw-backdrop-contrast: ;--tw-backdrop-grayscale: ;--tw-backdrop-hue-rotate: ;--tw-backdrop-invert: ;--tw-backdrop-opacity: ;--tw-backdrop-saturate: ;--tw-backdrop-sepia: }.relative{position:relative}.mx-auto{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}.mx-6{margin-left:1.5rem;margin-right:1.5rem}.ml-4{margin-left:1rem}.mt-16{margin-top:4rem}.mt-6{margin-top:1.5rem}.mt-4{margin-top:1rem}.-mt-px{margin-top:-1px}.mr-1{margin-right:0.25rem}.flex{display:flex}.inline-flex{display:inline-flex}.grid{display:grid}.h-16{height:4rem}.h-7{height:1.75rem}.h-6{height:1.5rem}.h-5{height:1.25rem}.min-h-screen{min-height:100vh}.w-auto{width:auto}.w-16{width:4rem}.w-7{width:1.75rem}.w-6{width:1.5rem}.w-5{width:1.25rem}.max-w-7xl{max-width:80rem}.shrink-0{flex-shrink:0}.scale-100{--tw-scale-x:1;--tw-scale-y:1;transform:translate(var(--tw-translate-x), var(--tw-translate-y)) rotate(var(--tw-rotate)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x)) skewY(var(--tw-skew-y)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x)) scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y))}.grid-cols-1{grid-template-columns:repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr))}.items-center{align-items:center}.justify-center{justify-content:center}.gap-6{gap:1.5rem}.gap-4{gap:1rem}.self-center{align-self:center}.rounded-lg{border-radius:0.5rem}.rounded-full{border-radius:9999px}.bg-gray-100{--tw-bg-opacity:1;background-color:rgb(243 244 246 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))}.bg-white{--tw-bg-opacity:1;background-color:rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))}.bg-red-50{--tw-bg-opacity:1;background-color:rgb(254 242 242 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))}.bg-dots-darker{background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='30' height='30' viewBox='0 0 30 30' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M1.22676 0C1.91374 0 2.45351 0.539773 2.45351 1.22676C2.45351 1.91374 1.91374 2.45351 1.22676 2.45351C0.539773 2.45351 0 1.91374 0 1.22676C0 0.539773 0.539773 0 1.22676 0Z' fill='rgba(0,0,0,0.07)'/%3E%3C/svg%3E")}.from-gray-700\/50{--tw-gradient-from:rgb(55 65 81 / 0.5);--tw-gradient-to:rgb(55 65 81 / 0);--tw-gradient-stops:var(--tw-gradient-from), var(--tw-gradient-to)}.via-transparent{--tw-gradient-to:rgb(0 0 0 / 0);--tw-gradient-stops:var(--tw-gradient-from), transparent, var(--tw-gradient-to)}.bg-center{background-position:center}.stroke-red-500{stroke:#ef4444}.stroke-gray-400{stroke:#9ca3af}.p-6{padding:1.5rem}.px-6{padding-left:1.5rem;padding-right:1.5rem}.text-center{text-align:center}.text-right{text-align:right}.text-xl{font-size:1.25rem;line-height:1.75rem}.text-sm{font-size:0.875rem;line-height:1.25rem}.font-semibold{font-weight:600}.leading-relaxed{line-height:1.625}.text-gray-600{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:rgb(75 85 99 / var(--tw-text-opacity))}.text-gray-900{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:rgb(17 24 39 / var(--tw-text-opacity))}.text-gray-500{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:rgb(107 114 128 / var(--tw-text-opacity))}.underline{-webkit-text-decoration-line:underline;text-decoration-line:underline}.antialiased{-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}.shadow-2xl{--tw-shadow:0 25px 50px -12px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.25);--tw-shadow-colored:0 25px 50px -12px var(--tw-shadow-color);box-shadow:var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-ring-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-shadow)}.shadow-gray-500\/20{--tw-shadow-color:rgb(107 114 128 / 0.2);--tw-shadow:var(--tw-shadow-colored)}.transition-all{transition-property:all;transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);transition-duration:150ms}.selection\:bg-red-500 *::selection{--tw-bg-opacity:1;background-color:rgb(239 68 68 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))}.selection\:text-white *::selection{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity))}.selection\:bg-red-500::selection{--tw-bg-opacity:1;background-color:rgb(239 68 68 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))}.selection\:text-white::selection{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity))}.hover\:text-gray-900:hover{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:rgb(17 24 39 / var(--tw-text-opacity))}.hover\:text-gray-700:hover{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:rgb(55 65 81 / var(--tw-text-opacity))}.focus\:rounded-sm:focus{border-radius:0.125rem}.focus\:outline:focus{outline-style:solid}.focus\:outline-2:focus{outline-width:2px}.focus\:outline-red-500:focus{outline-color:#ef4444}.group:hover .group-hover\:stroke-gray-600{stroke:#4b5563}.z-10{z-index: 10}@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference){.motion-safe\:hover\:scale-\[1\.01\]:hover{--tw-scale-x:1.01;--tw-scale-y:1.01;transform:translate(var(--tw-translate-x), var(--tw-translate-y)) rotate(var(--tw-rotate)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x)) skewY(var(--tw-skew-y)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x)) scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y))}}@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark){.dark\:bg-gray-900{--tw-bg-opacity:1;background-color:rgb(17 24 39 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))}.dark\:bg-gray-800\/50{background-color:rgb(31 41 55 / 0.5)}.dark\:bg-red-800\/20{background-color:rgb(153 27 27 / 0.2)}.dark\:bg-dots-lighter{background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='30' height='30' viewBox='0 0 30 30' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M1.22676 0C1.91374 0 2.45351 0.539773 2.45351 1.22676C2.45351 1.91374 1.91374 2.45351 1.22676 2.45351C0.539773 2.45351 0 1.91374 0 1.22676C0 0.539773 0.539773 0 1.22676 0Z' fill='rgba(255,255,255,0.07)'/%3E%3C/svg%3E")}.dark\:bg-gradient-to-bl{background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom left, var(--tw-gradient-stops))}.dark\:stroke-gray-600{stroke:#4b5563}.dark\:text-gray-400{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:rgb(156 163 175 / var(--tw-text-opacity))}.dark\:text-white{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity))}.dark\:shadow-none{--tw-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow-colored:0 0 #0000;box-shadow:var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-ring-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-shadow)}.dark\:ring-1{--tw-ring-offset-shadow:var(--tw-ring-inset) 0 0 0 var(--tw-ring-offset-width) var(--tw-ring-offset-color);--tw-ring-shadow:var(--tw-ring-inset) 0 0 0 calc(1px + var(--tw-ring-offset-width)) var(--tw-ring-color);box-shadow:var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow), var(--tw-ring-shadow), var(--tw-shadow, 0 0 #0000)}.dark\:ring-inset{--tw-ring-inset:inset}.dark\:ring-white\/5{--tw-ring-color:rgb(255 255 255 / 0.05)}.dark\:hover\:text-white:hover{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity))}.group:hover .dark\:group-hover\:stroke-gray-400{stroke:#9ca3af}}@media (min-width: 640px){.sm\:fixed{position:fixed}.sm\:top-0{top:0px}.sm\:right-0{right:0px}.sm\:ml-0{margin-left:0px}.sm\:flex{display:flex}.sm\:items-center{align-items:center}.sm\:justify-center{justify-content:center}.sm\:justify-between{justify-content:space-between}.sm\:text-left{text-align:left}.sm\:text-right{text-align:right}}@media (min-width: 768px){.md\:grid-cols-2{grid-template-columns:repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr))}}@media (min-width: 1024px){.lg\:gap-8{gap:2rem}.lg\:p-8{padding:2rem}}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="antialiased">
    </body>
</html>
```

These are the steps that I took to setup the project:

1. `laravel new project`
2. `composer require orchid/platform`
3. `php artisan orchid:install`

These are the steps that I took to host the app on Hostinger:

1. Create website.
2. Go to Advanced > PHP Configuration and choose PHP 8.1
3. Go to Advanced > GIT and generate an SSH key and add it as a deploy key to your repo.
4. Then add the repo with an ssh url from Github and specify the correct branch. The directory can be left empty.
5. Go to Databases > Management and add a MySQL database.
6. Next, go to Advanced > SSH Access and open Git Bash and paste the login command from SSH into the terminal and enter your password.
7. Then navigate to your domain, so cd domains > cd {{domain}} > cd public_html
8. Run this command: `cp .env.example .env`
9. Run this command: `nano .env` and add the database credentials and configure anything else needed.
10. Go to https://getcomposer.org/download and run the Command-line installation there in the terminal.
11. Run `php -v` if php is not 8.1 then run the commands below.
    a. Run `nano ~/.bashrc` and put this text in alias php='/opt/alt/php81/usr/bin/php'
    b. Enter next `. ~/.bashrc` off
12. Then run `php composer.phar install` next
13. Next, run `php artisan key:generate`
14. Next, run `php artisan migrate`
15. Next, run `php artisan storage:link`
16. After this, run `nano .htaccess` and put the following text in it

    Rewrite Engine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
17. Then run `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash` out
18. Then run the following commands:

    a. `export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"`

    b. `[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"`

    c. `[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"`
19. Next, run `nvm install 16.16`
20. Then run `npm install` and `npm run build`.

After these steps the Laravel website is deployed, but when I go to the [preview website](https://cms-event4-nl.preview-domain.com/) all the head tags are moved to the body tag.

Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this issue? Because support of Hostinger does not want to help me with this issue.
Repo: https://github.com/mvpdsolutions/test_hostinger

Comment: You're operating on the [preview domain](https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/2489693-how-to-see-your-website-content-without-a-domain#preview-website), so this is a feature you have enabled. Use your real domain instead (`cms-event4.nl` or similar), then the head will not end prematurely any longer as the preview div is not inserted early any longer. That feature is not well implemented on Hostingers' side, but their support is likely not able to change that. As preview is incompatible with your site, use the real domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>     <head> <div style="position:absolute;top:0;z-index:2147483647;display:flex;padding:16px;width:100%;background-color:#fff;box-shadow:0 0 6px rgba(29,30,32,.22)"id="hostinger-preview-banner"><div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;gap:8px;width:100%;font-family:"DM Sans";font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-size:14px;line-height:24px;color:#1d1e20"><svg fill="#fea419"height="24"part="svg"width="24"xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><path clip-rule="evenodd"d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12C2 17.52 6.48 22 12 22C17.52 22 22 17.52 22 12C22 6.48 17.52 2 12 2ZM13 17H11V15H13V17ZM13 13H11V7H13V13Z"fill-rule="evenodd"/></g></svg><div>This is a preview of a website by a customer of Hostinger</div></div><svg fill="#727586"height="24"part="svg"width="24"xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"onclick="document.getElementById(`hostinger-preview-banner`).style.display=`none`""style="cursor:pointer"><g><path clip-rule="evenodd"d="M19 6.41L17.59 5L12 10.59L6.41 5L5 6.41L10.59 12L5 17.59L6.41 19L12 13.41L17.59 19L19 17.59L13.41 12L19 6.41Z"fill-rule="evenodd"/></g></svg></div>
> ```

The preview site injects a `<div>` (which implicitly closes the `<head>` and starts the `<body>`) to tell you that it is a preview site.

Presumably the problem will go away when you turn preview mode off.